# Uniqueness of minimizer of the vector 1-norm of $QM$ over all real orthogonal matrices $Q$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization

Let $M\in \mathbb R^{d_1\times d_2}$ be a "fat" orthonormal matrix (so that $2d_1<d_2$ and $MM^T=I_{d_1}$) and $\|\cdot\|_1$ denotes the *vector* $1$-norm (not the *induced* $1$-norm) of a matrix, i.e. $\|X\|_1=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{d_1}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{d_2}|x_{ij}|$.

Is there a unique or essentially unique $d_1\times d_1$ real orthogonal matrix $Q_0$ that solves the minimization problem
$$\min\limits_{Q\in O_{d_1}(\mathbb R)}\|QM\|_1\ ?$$

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have changed some symbols and technical terms to the more customary ones. Please feel free to roll back if I have misread your question.